# npm ERR! code E403 When trying to upload private NPM Package via Github Actions

Tags: node.js, npm

I am following a tutorial which teaches you how to upload a private NPM package using Github Actions and Packages.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CNC0QBCY-Y&ab_channel=BrianMorrison

I created a simple Javascript function, created a Github repository and created a simple workflow using Github actions, the workflow looks like this:

```
name: guides

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  publish-gpr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12
          registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/
          scope: '@xxxxxxxx'
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
```

When commiting the workflow, I see this error on the step npm publish:

```
npm notice 
npm notice   guides@1.0.0
npm notice === Tarball Contents === 
npm notice 12.9kB index.js                  
npm notice 306B   package.json              
npm notice 426B   .github/workflows/main.yml
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          guides                                  
npm notice version:       1.0.0                                   
npm notice package size:  4.0 kB                                  
npm notice unpacked size: 13.6 kB                                 
npm notice shasum:        5857fc3a423f8c155d4f56fc01a3937551fccf91
npm notice integrity:     sha512-32eff6KJAOILQ[...]62lGoBMyl4BMA==
npm notice total files:   3                                       
npm notice 
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/@xxxxxxxxxxxx/guides - Permission installation not allowed to Create organization package
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-05-23T14_59_01_579Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

How do you stop this error from coming up when committing the workflow?